# Render millions of cubes with non-static position in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm doing my own **minecraft game** in three.js. All goes well, but I came across the problem - blocks in my game is *lagging*.

I know that good idea is to merge it like in example: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/10/05/performance-merging-geometry/

But when I merge all blocks I cannot changing single position and also remove too :(

I need meshes that are static and have got dynamic position

Comment: Instead of merging the geometries consider to use instanced rendering like demonstrated in the following [example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing). I recommend you study the general approach first and then dive into the `three.js` implementation.

Comment: Merged geometries are 15-30% faster than instancing in my tests. As for making a minecraft game, the whole point is to write code to generate the optimal mesh. Just merging geometry is not the solution. You need to look the 6 or 23 voxels around each voxel and decide if you really need a plane on each side of the voxel. For example if there is a voxel on it's left than it doesn't need a left face and the voxel on the left doesn't need a right face since they are touching each other those faces can't be seen. See http://voxeljs.com/

Comment: You might find [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-voxel-geometry.html) useful